# Why Segmentation fault (core dumped) occurs when im trying to use matrices with functions?

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array, segmentation-fault

I'm starting to see functions in classes, but i have some doubts. Why my code throws "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" when i use them with functions?.

I already tried using global variables with the matrix, but i want to use them as local variables and pass them to functions.

```c
void matrixDimension();
void fillMatrix();
void imprimirmatrix();

int main()
    {

    int dimension;
    matrixDimension(&dimension);
    int matrix[dimension][dimension];

    srand(time(NULL));
    fillMatrix(matrix, dimension);
    }

void matrixDimension(int *dimension)
    {
    do{
        printf("\nEnter the size of the matrix:");
        scanf("%i", dimension);
        }while(2>*dimension);
    }

void fillMatrix(int dimension, int matrix[dimension][dimension])
    {
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<dimension;i++)
        for(j=0;j<dimension;j++)
            matrix[i][j]=rand()%2;
    }
```

When i compile it with gcc, sometimes it appears Segmentation fault (core dumped) error randomly. How can i fix this error?

Comment: You're passing the arguments in the wrong order. `fillMatrix` expects `dimension` and `matrix`, but you pass `matrix` followed by `dimension`.

Comment: You should check the return value of `scanf`, and check that `dimension` holds a sensible value before doing `int matrix[dimension][dimension]`. It should be greater than 0 and less than about 500

Comment: Right, it shoul be `fillMatrix(dimension, matrix)`.

Comment: Using function prototypes would have given you a compiler diagnostic for the problem highlighted by user3386109

Comment: Thanks, i fixed the order in fillMatrix(dimension,matrix) like you guys said and it  got fixed.

Comment: Please put the solution in an answer and mark it. It will help us ignore this question as it is solved, and saves us time. And, raise the warning level of your compiler to the max!